# Batch load Java application configurable rules required

Tags: java, architecture, configuration, batch-processing

I am developing an application in Java. I have to upload data from flat text files into a DB tables. Problem is, as the application is used by several vendors who have different systems, which can generate different flat text files.
For example Vendor V1 may generate a text file  where certain field starts at column 10 and another Vendor V2 may generate a text file where same filed may start at column 12.
So In a way I have different parsing rules for different vendors.

What I want to achieve is to create an application that loads “rules” from some specific place(may be some configurable file). These rules will be applied on flat text file to generate the data.

Afterwards there will be some transformations applied on that data ,before saving it to DB.
Those transformations will again be vendor specific . For example vendor V1 may divide certain field with 10 before sending it to DB , while Vendor V2 may divide the same field 20 before saving it .

How can I achieve this? What is the best practice you recommend?

I was thinking if I could create a MDB for this .

Use JPA for saving the data in DB (not sure if this is a gud idea ,as there could be 50-60k records)
Not sure what should I use to have parsing and transforming rules configurable .

Any Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you learn how to use Java reflection. You can find an introduction to this in a free training course I wrote called [Java Reflection Explained Simply](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/training-courses.html#training-java-reflection). Your application can use reflection to load a plug-in: and you can write a separate plug-in for each vendor's file format. Your application can use an entry in a configuration file to specify the name of the Java class that implements the plug-in to be loaded.

You said that the work flow is basically: (1) parse an input file to obtain data; (2) transform the data; (3) write the transformed data to a database. If step 2 is tightly coupled to step 1, then I suggest that each plug-in should implement both steps 1 and 2. But if step 2 is independent of step 1, then your application should load two plug-ins: one for step 1, and another plug-in for step 2.

If you ever decide that you need to load the transformed data into different backends (a database, write to a text file, send as an email, and so on), then step 3 could also be implemented via a plug-in architecture.